# Beautiful soup get tag values that follow after the matched tag value

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, tags

I have a code where I need to look for the div tag that has the value 'Lead' , once that tag is found in the code it looks for the immediate div with value 'name' and then extracts the email id in the immediate next tag, such that my code outputs the name and the email id as follows

John Doe john.doe@johndoe.com

```
 <div class="badge memberType Member long notAffiliatedContact">Lead</div>
 <div class="name"><a href="/10016/John Doe">John Doe</a></div>
 <div class="posted"><span class="label">Email: </span><span class="value break-word">john.doe@johndoe.com</span></div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the next element using `findNext()`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="badge memberType Member long notAffiliatedContact">Lead</div>
 <div class="name"><a href="/10016/John Doe">John Doe</a></div>
 <div class="posted"><span class="label">Email: </span><span class="value break-word">john.doe@johndoe.com</span></div>
 """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "badge"})
for div in divs:
    if div.text == "Lead":
        name = div.findNext('div')
        email = name.findNext('span').findNext('span')
print(name.text, email.text)
#John Doe john.doe@johndoe.com
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though I have a quick question why is the term 'name.findNext' used here?

Comment: It's because the code finds the `div` containing 'Lead', and assigns the next `div` to `name`. It will then find the next `span` after `name` using `name.findNext()` and assigns it to `email`. It's equivalent would be `div.findNext('div').findNext()`